# Grab Youtube video-ID from XML element

Tags: jquery, xml, parsing, split

I'm coding an app in Phonegap and I'm trying to extract the video-ID from an XML file.

This is part of the XML containing the iFrame

```
<lees-verder>
<![CDATA[
<p><iframe width="720" height="396" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/53_qvMQfvOE?rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></p>
]]>
</lees-verder>
```

This is the Jquery I use to parse "lees-verder".

```
var long = myObj.find('lees-verder').text();
```

My question is: How do I write the Jquery action more specific, so it splits the element and gives me the 11-character-long video-ID?
I started with this, but I don't know if I'm going the right direction

```
var ytube = long.substring(long.
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a regular expression once you have the text in the variable `long`:

```
var ytube = null;
var match = /embed\/([A-Za-z0-9_]+)/.exec(long);
if(match) ytube = match[1]; // Found it!
```

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick! When I use `alert(ytube);` and there is no iFrame, it alerts "null". I fixed this by replacing `null` with `""`. An alert-box still pops up, but that doesn't matter. Thanks again!